# C# Linq Query from a list to select only records which have same id from another list

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a list of object. I would like to select item from the list and perform foreach operation on the selected items.And then Get the Data which have that Site.

C# Linq Query from a list to select only records which have same id from another list

**Model**

List of Sites

```
public class Site
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int SiteNo{ get; set; }          
}

public class StudentSite
{
    public string Username{ get; set; }
    public string { get; set; }
    public IList<Site> SiteNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateReceived { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string DataEntryUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int? Count { get; set; }
}

var user = repository.Get(userid);  //it return me the list of sites 10 sites 

results_temp12 = (from workstation in _entitiesCTRS2.AidsM.OrderBy(c => c.Lab_ID )       
                 where user.User_InvSites.ToList().
                 ForEach(c => c.Inv_Site.SITE_NO
                    .Where( w=> workstation.Site_Number == c.Inv_Site.SITE_NO)
                    .ToList()) 
                    select new 
                    StudentSite
                    {
                        firstname = workstation.First_Name,
                        CreatedDate = workstation.Entered_dt,
                        scanid = workstation.Scan_ID,
                        labid = workstation.Lab_ID,
                        SiteNo = workstation.Site_Number,
                        DateReceived = workstation.Date_Received,
                        DataEntryUser = workstation.Entered_By                                
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: *Pro tip:* please tidy up your code and question formatting - it's unbearable and unreadable.

Comment: How is `user` used?  Why did you get it from `repository` and not use it?

Comment: @Kyle when i am trying to add user in my Query i am getting erro can not convert void to bool

Comment: @Kyle    where user.User_InvSites.ToList().ForEach(c => c.Inv_Site.SITE_NO.Where(w=> workstation.Site_Number == c.Inv_Site.SITE_NO).ToList())

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty easy:

```
list1.Where(item1 => list2.Any(item2 => item1.Id == item2.Id));
```

This will give you every item in `list1` whose ID is in `list2`.

Answer (score 0):

It's maddeningly unclear on what you want.  But two possibilities I get from your question:

```
// Inner join: Only returns foos where foo.Id exists in bars
var results = from foo in foos
              join bar in bars on foo.Id equals bar.Id
              select foo;

// Gets all foos if it contains at least one element found in another list
var results = from foo in foos
              where foo.Sites.Select(f => f.Id).Any(s => bars.Any(b => s == b.Id))
              select foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `where` condition to use `Any` instead of `Foreach`.

```
results_temp12 = (from workstation in _entitiesCTRS2.AidsM.OrderBy(c => c.Lab_ID)
                          where user.User_InvSites.ToList().Any(c => c.Inv_Site.SITE_NO == workstation.Site_Number)
                          //where user.User_InvSites.ToList().ForEach(c => c.Inv_Site.SITE_NO.Where(w => workstation.Site_Number == c.Inv_Site.SITE_NO).ToList())
                          select new StudentSite
                          {
                              firstname = workstation.First_Name,
                              CreatedDate = workstation.Entered_dt,
                              scanid = workstation.Scan_ID,
                              labid = workstation.Lab_ID,
                              SiteNo = workstation.Site_Number,
                              DateReceived = workstation.Date_Received,
                              DataEntryUser = workstation.Entered_By
                          }).ToList();
```

You can either use `Join` on Site_No and transform the result.

```
results_temp12 = (from workstation in _entitiesCTRS2.AidsM.OrderBy(c => c.Lab_ID)
                          join user_site in user.User_InvSites on workstation.Site_Number equals user_site.SITE_NO
                          select new StudentSite
                          {
                              firstname = workstation.First_Name,
                              CreatedDate = workstation.Entered_dt,
                              scanid = workstation.Scan_ID,
                              labid = workstation.Lab_ID,
                              SiteNo = workstation.Site_Number,
                              DateReceived = workstation.Date_Received,
                              DataEntryUser = workstation.Entered_By
                          }).ToList();
```

Comment: But i getting error Unable to create a constant value of type '?'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CTLSModel.User_InvSites] ToList[User_InvSites](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CTLSModel.User_InvSites])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.